# Указание пути к libm и libc при запуске gcc/g++

Tags: linux, g++

Ведётся разработка под разные ОС разной разрядности. Рабочая ОС - ArchLinux x64. Ввиду не желания использования виртуальных машин было решено создавать виртуальные окружения с минимальным количеством элементов системы, под которую ведётся разработка. Кроме того, чтобы была возможность использовать свежий компилятор, я перемещаю в соответствующую папку (например, /mnt/testOS1/bin, /mnt/testOS1/usr/bin ...) свои бинарники gcc/g++ с заменой. Далее следует chroot, потом сборка и запуск.

Всё бы ничего, но когда целевая система имеет разрядность x32, начинаются проблемы. Не смотря на то, что я поставил gcc-multilib, сам бинарник gcc/g++ имеет разрядность x64 и для запуска ищет соответствующие его разрядности библиотеки (libc и libm), в противном случае выдаёт ...wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32. Менять библиотеки, очевидно, нельзя, чтобы вся система не поехала.

Решением задачи с приведёнными начальными условиями я вижу указание путей к этим библиотекам нужной разрядности в момент запуска g++. Возможно ли такое?

Кроме того, я хотел бы услышать другие, более правильные, варианты реализации подобной системы разработки.

Comment: то, что Вы делаете, очень похоже на vagrant. Вполне возможно, что для него уже написали конфиги под Ваш случай. И он использует виртуалбокс. Но очень-очень прозрачно.

Но я бы попробовал завести все это под докером. Это позволит не засорять основную систему и иметь готовые "наборы" на разные случаи.

Comment: @KoVadim то есть я могу, допустим, запустить g++ своей системы из окружения другой системы, используя docker?

Comment: внутри докера можно поставить нужный g++. Таким образом, когда нужно будет перейти на другую машину (а то и ось), просто переноситься докерфайл (который текстовый) и все подымается.

Comment: @KoVadim звучит удобно. Осталось разобраться... Спасибо!

Comment: *сам бинарник gcc/g++ имеет разрядность x64* — что-то мешает запускать экземпляр, собранный для другой архитектуры?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin для другой архитектуры я могу только из исходников собрать, верно? В таком случае ничего не мешает, но какую опцию надо указать при конфигурации/сборке?

Comment: @AccumPlus, я не знаю, как там обстоят дела с multiarch в вашем дистрибутиве, а в *debian*-е (и наследниках), например, установить пакет для 32-битной архитектуры в системе с «родной» 64-битной — [достаточно просто](https://wiki.debian.org/ru/Multiarch/HOWTO).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да есть в arch соответствующий multilib пакет, но компилятор при этом всё равно остаётся верен 64-битной архитектуре. Это просто добавляет ему умений компилировать под нужную архитектуру.