# Запуск gcc с линковкой к другим библиотекам

Tags: linux, bash, gcc, ld, libc

Задумка может показаться странной.
Создаю окружение для разработки под linux. Создал каталог /home/user/myOS. В нём usr, usr/bin, usr/lib и ссылки bin->usr/bin, lib->usr/lib.
Копирую туда необходимые бинарники и либы из одной операционной системы (назовём её OSold, она старее). Однако, я хочу компилировать из-под этого окружения новым компилятором, поэтому g++ и gcc копирую из другой системы (назовём её OSnew, она свежая). (не уверен, что без актуальной libc у меня что-то получится). К слову, окружение создаётся на OSnew.

Захожу в окружение через chroot. При запуске компилятора происходит следующее:

```
bash-3.00# g++
g++: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by g++)
g++: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.4' not found (required by g++)
```

Я так понял, что эти либы ему нужны именно для запуска. Создаю отдельный каталог: /home/user/myOS/home/mylibs. В него кладу актуальные библиотеки libc. Снова chroot, а потом делаю следующее:

```
bash-3.00# LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/mylibs g++
```

Но он всё равно сначала просматривает стандартные директории и падает на вышеуказанных ошибках. Пробовал и через export - всё одно.

Подскажите, как насильно указать оболочке использовать именно мои либы при запуске исполняемого файла? И вообще, что необходимо, чтобы LD_LIBRARY_PATH нормально отрабатывал? (А то я вполне мог недокопировать чего-то важного).

*По поводу дубликата вопроса*

Тот вопрос был о несовпадении битности систем. Здесь же вопрос о версиях библиотек.

***UPD***

*Скорее всего в рамках этого вопроса такое сильное изменение недопустимо. Но пусть это решают модераторы.*

В общем chroot-ы можно забыть. На реальной старой системе запускаются программы, скомпилированные на новой системе с использованием следующей команды:

```
g++ -m32 main.cpp -o Main -Wl,--hash-style=sysv
```

Однако, при использовании конструкций нового стандарта C++ выдаёт следующее:

```
./Main: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBC_3.4.21' not found (required by ./Main)
```

Попробовал указать путь к новой либе (очевидно, 32-битной):

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/temp/mylibs/" ./Main
./Main: error while loading shared libraries: /home/temp/mylibs/libstdc++.so.6: ELF file OS ABI invalid
```

Есть идеи, как это можно решить?

Comment: А вы уверены что gcc ищет не по заранее заданному пути библиотеки? Тогда LD_LIBRARY_PATH уже не поможет. А вообще попробуйте лучше для вашего окружения собрать заново все библиотеки и раскрутить компилятор. В качестве инструкции можете воспользоваться [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) (конец 4й главы, 5 и начало 6ой, если мне память не изменяет).

Comment: @Flowneee Мне кажется, что всё же bash ищет, а не gcc. Он просматривает стандартные пути, в том числе и те, что указаны в LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Но, по всей видимости, старые либы его "устраивают", поэтому он тормозит и скармливает их исполняемой программе. Ранее я задолбался с соответствием битности систем. 64битные библиотеки оказались "сильно не подходящими" для 32битной системы, и bash не пытался их скормить, а шёл дальше, в том числе и в LD_LIBRARY_PATH, где лежали заветные 32битные либы. Да, всё это лишь мои догадки. Как это на самом деле - я не знаю.

Comment: Есть еще вариант такой, что chroot запускается для `/home/user/myOS`, а библиотеки лежат в `/home/mylibs`, тогда очевидо, что из под chroot никак не увидеть эту директорию, ну и дальше соответственно.

Comment: @Flowneee не не не, имеется ввиду /home внутри окружения. Сек, поправлю

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Указание пути к libm и libc при запуске gcc/g++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600203/%d0%a3%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%ba-libm-%d0%b8-libc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-gcc-g)

Comment: А почему просто не положить либы в `/home/user/myOS/lib`?

Comment: а линух какой ?

Comment: @Flownee у них полностью совпадают названия

Comment: @Majestio старый - МСВС3.0 с ядром 2.4.32, новый - ArchLinux свежий

Comment: Еще ведь проблема в том, что сам GCC запускается, но в процессе компиляции не находит библиотеку, соответсвенно и собрать исполняемый файл не может. Может он просто не умеет искать `libc` в альтернативных `/lib` папках? Я подозреваю что путь поиска этой библиотеки зашивается в процессе компиляции компилятора.

Comment: Прочитайте [вот это](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Glibc2-HOWTO-6.html), возможно просто нужно при задании опций компиляции указать явно где лежит `libc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AccumPlus , написал небольшой шел-скрип, который, надеюсь поможет разобраться с путями к библиотекам. Скрипт создает в каталоге запуска три программки, и три динамически-линкуемые библиотеки к ним, соответственно. Раскидая программки и либы по сhroot-овым каталогам, можно будет оценить правильность настройки окружений.

**Запуск скрипта**

- заходим в систему обычным пользователем
- создаем пустой каталог `mkdir -p $HOME/HelloPrograms && cd $HOME/HelloPrograms`
- создаем файл скрипта. например, `build-hello.sh`
- запускаем `sh build-hello.sh`
- три программки соберутся и запустятся
- все, можно раскидывать по chroot-ам

**build-hello.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

function BuildHello {
  echo "#include \"HelloLibrary-$1.h\"" > HelloLibrary-$1.c
  echo "#include <stdio.h>" >> HelloLibrary-$1.c
  echo " " >> HelloLibrary-$1.c
  echo "void  Hello$1(const char* msg) {" >> HelloLibrary-$1.c
  echo "  printf(\"Hello, %s-$1!\\n\",msg);" >> HelloLibrary-$1.c
  echo "}" >> HelloLibrary-$1.c  
  echo "#pragma once" > HelloLibrary-$1.h
  echo "void  Hello$1(const char* msg);" >> HelloLibrary-$1.h
  echo "#include <stdio.h>" > HelloProgram-$1.c
  echo "#include \"HelloLibrary-$1.h\"" >> HelloProgram-$1.c
  echo " " >> HelloProgram-$1.c
  echo "int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {" >> HelloProgram-$1.c
  echo "  Hello$1(\"Program\");" >> HelloProgram-$1.c
  echo "  return 0;" >> HelloProgram-$1.c
  echo "}" >> HelloProgram-$1.c
  gcc -c -fPIC HelloLibrary-$1.c -o HelloLibrary-$1.o
  gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libHelloLibrary-$1.so -o libHelloLibrary-$1.so HelloLibrary-$1.o
  gcc HelloProgram-$1.c -o HelloProgram-$1 -L. -lHelloLibrary-$1
  rm -f *.{c,h,o}
}

clear

if [ "$(whoami)" == 'root' ]; then 
  echo "Ахтунг: под учетной записью рута работать отказываюсь!" 
  exit 1 
fi

for Num in {1..3}
do
  BuildHello $Num
  ./HelloProgram-$Num
done
```

Надеюсь, немного поможет в поисках :)

РS. Забыл ... для просмотра требуемых библиотек запускаем, например:

`ldd $HOME/HelloPrograms/HelloProgram-1`

**ADD: Построение инструментария для кросс-компиляции**

Раз в конце концов всеж уточнили цель, и она оказалась - построение инструментария для кросс-компиляции, то продолжу ответ.

- перво-наперво читаем документацию, как это все делается, например, вот [это](https://sourceware.org/ml/crossgcc/2005-08/msg00114/l-cross-ltr.pdf) и [это](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler), и [это](http://marcelog.github.io/articles/cross_freebsd_compiler_in_linux.html)
- заходим на сайт http://mxe.cc, там забираем и устанавливаем набор кросс-компиляторов для Windows (там есть 8 комплектов x32/x64/shared/static/posix/win). Отличается узкой направленностью (только для Win), это дает более хорошие результаты адаптации по сравнению с подобными инструментами (например, crossdev от Gentoo/Funtoo Linux)
- очередной неплохой инструментарий - [crosstools-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/), многоцелевой
- clang/LLVM-based набор для кросскомпиляции для встраиваемых систем - [ELLCC](http://ellcc.org/), хотя (?) в целях обозначены ARM, i386, Mips, PowerPC, X86_64

Вобщем, начальной инфы, думаю, достаточно. Вопрос не совсем простой - одной темой на ruSO явно не обойтись.

Comment: Вы немного не поняли. Мне стоит поправить вопрос, чтобы не возникало непоняток. Мне нужно, чтобы Bash запускал gcc указав ему новую libc для линковки, но сам gcc компилировал файлы, указывая линковщику использовать старую libc. Это вообще возможно?

Comment: А погодите... Это я не понял. Я компилирую программы в родной среде новым компилятором с новыми либами, а потом готовые программы кидаю в chroot-ы, где лежат старые либы... Что ж попробую, спасибо

Comment: Вы натолкнули меня на мысль... В конечном итоге, я сумел добиться запуска на старой системе программ, скомпиленных на новой системе, компилируя их следующим образом: g++ -m32 main.cpp -o Main -Wl,--hash-style=sysv.  Однако, возникла новая проблема. При использовании конструкций новых стандартов у меня выпадает ошибка: version 'GLIBC_3.4.21' not found. При указании LD_LIBRARY_PATH выдаёт следующее: libstdc++.so.6: ELF file OS ABI invalid. Пока что не сумел победить эту проблему.

Comment: Нет, так нельзя. Надо по шагам. 1) Создали окружение и скопировали туда нужные файлы 2) Убедились в работоспособности gcc и утилия от binutils 3) Бинарники и либы с "новой" системы просто так копировать нельзя, нужно собирать 4) Поэтому пытаемся (имхо, наиболее легкий вариант) собрать свежий clang. Результат: старый утиль и старый gcc, старые либы, новый clang. Если все пройдет нормально - задача решена. Да, вполне возможно придется пересобирать libstdc++

Comment: собирать компилятор и новые либы Вы имеете ввиду в окружении?

Comment: Да. Но, если честно, я не совсем понимаю какую цель вы преследуете? Зачем все эти фокусы со старым/новым окружением?

Comment: хороший вопрос на самом деле. Так была поставлена задача. А вообще, глобальная задача - реализовать несколько окружений, соответствующих определённым ОС, и обеспечить возможность компилировать под каждую из них программы, используя современный компилятор и стандарты языка. Я никогда этого не делал, и мне сказали, что можно попробовать закинуть новый компилятор в старое окружение. Отсюда поплыли проблемы и различные варианты обхода. Если есть общепринятый отточенный механизм такого рода кросс-компиляции, то я с удовольствием хотел бы о нём узнать!

Comment: Дополнил свой ответ выше некоторой инфой о построении кросс-компиляторов. Для Linux->Win сам таким пользуюсь (mxe.cc).

Comment: Спасибо) помечу как ответ